# C++ Assignment - Why isn't the push button working?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to do the following on an Arduino:

> Task: Create a toggle switch that controls when 3 LEDs switch on (at the same time). In a toggle switch, when the button is pressed, the LEDs switch on. When it is pressed again, the LEDs switch off.

My pushbutton isn't turning on to turn on the LEDs
The code is:

```
// C++ code
//Declare
int ledPin13 = 13;
int ledPin12 = 12;
int ledPin11 = 11;
int buttonPin = 1;
int buttonState;

//State if input or output
void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin , INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin13 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin12 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin11 , OUTPUT);
}

//Stage 3 - Code what you want to do (according to psuedocode)
void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin13 , HIGH);
 
    digitalWrite(ledPin12 , HIGH);
  
    digitalWrite(ledPin11 , HIGH);

  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin13 , LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin12 , LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin11 , LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're only lighting the LEDs while the button is held.  You need to switch their state (on to off, or off to on) when the button is pressed, and do nothing when it isn't.

Comment: It also helps to know what you are working with? Pi, Arduino, Ti microcontroller?

Comment: You may also have problems with switch bounce after you deal with the other issue.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention im using an arduino and breadboard on a website called tinkercad

Comment: You can add a debug print into your of statements to figure out, if the incoming or outgoing signal is a problem

Comment: The thing is tinkercad says theres no issue in the code, its simply that the pushbutton doesnt turn on

Comment: That may be a better fit on [Arduino SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/). I also suggest you put a photo of your wiring and a schematics of the circuit.
Without that, it could be literally anything, from poor contact to burned pin and simply things being wired where they should not.

Comment: its on an online website called tinkercad

Answer (score 1):

It is because your program continuously reads a state. It means the time of pressing the button in compare with the checking of the state by MCU is too mush . for fixing this problem you have two options:

1. Checking the button. You have to check the state but It is better
   to use debouncing which means adding delay between two reads.

```cpp
bool LEDstate = false;
void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
    {
      delay(500);  // to be stable
      if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
        {
          if (LEDstate == false)
            {
              digitalWrite(ledPin13, HIGH);
              digitalWrite(ledPin12, HIGH);
              digitalWrite(ledPin11, HIGH);
              LEDstate = true;
            }
          else
            {
              digitalWrite(ledPin13, LOW);
              digitalWrite(ledPin12, LOW);
              digitalWrite(ledPin11, LOW);
              LEDstate = false;
            }
            while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH); // wait to release
        }
    }
}
```

2. Inverse reading, which means you have to read the pressing and then wait to release to change the state of LEDs

```cpp
bool LEDstate = false;
void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
    {
      delay(100);  // to be stable
      while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH); // wait to release

      if (LEDstate == false)
        {
          digitalWrite(ledPin13, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(ledPin12, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(ledPin11, HIGH);
          LEDstate = true;
        }
      else
        {
          digitalWrite(ledPin13, LOW);
          digitalWrite(ledPin12, LOW);
          digitalWrite(ledPin11, LOW);
          LEDstate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool toggleState = 0;    
buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
delay(100);
if( buttonState == 1)
{
    if(toggleState)
        toggleState = 0;
    else
        toggleState = 1;
}
if(toggleState)
{
    digitalWrite(ledPin13 , HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin12 , HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin11 , HIGH);
}
else
{
    digitalWrite(ledPin13 , LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin12 , LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin11 , LOW);
}
```

Comment: when you press the button it will change toggleState and based on toggleState the leds will turn on or off